# Find remaining days month week left of your age

Tags: python

*You can use Python in this*.

Given an age input in years (no input for months or days), and assuming the life expectancy of 90 years (assume the person will be living only till the age of 90years), find the *remaining* months, days and weeks he/she is having.

Print the output using f-strings in Python.

If age input is 12, the output should look exactly like this:

You have 28470 days, 4056 weeks, and 936 months left.

Warning: Your output should match exactly as above, also even the positions of commas and full stops.

Other example inputs and outputs:

Input: 53 
Output: 13505 days, 1924 weeks, 444 months

Input: 90 
Output: 0 days, 0 weeks and 0 months

Input: 56 
Output: 12410 days, 1768 weeks, 408 months

Comment: This looks like homework, what have you tried on your own?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this a ***literal*** homework dump?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, You can use Python in this, lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
age = input("What is your current age? ")
ageint=int(age)
yearremain=90-ageint
days=yearremain*365
week=yearremain*52
month=yearremain*12
print(f"you have {days} days, {week} weeks, and {month} months left.")
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).